# Planned trajectory times different from actual robot times

Tags: ros2, moveit, simulation, ros-humble, moveit2

I am using moveit2 Humble and Isaac Sim from Nvidia.

I use the `MoveGroupInterface` to plan a trajectory with 4 waypoints. Each waypoint is planned with a call to `plan` and then I concatenate all waypoints using `IterativeParabolicTimeParameterization`.

```
trajectory_processing::IterativeParabolicTimeParameterization iptp;
bool success = iptp.computeTimeStamps(trajectory);
```

Where `trajectory` is simply the concatenation of all the points from the previous `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan` plan results.

This works and I can generate a nice path for Isaac. However, I noticed that the calculated duration from moveit is almost twice slower than what the robot finally achieves. (you can get the duration using `trajectory.getDuration()` or simply reading the timestamp from the `JointTrajectory` message).

Both moveit and Isaac share the same URDF file with the right velocity limits.
Moveit estimates roughly 5.6 seconds while the robot actually completes the route within 2.4 seconds.

I guess I have two questions:

- Is the duration estimated by moveit, returned by `IterativeParabolicTimeParameterization` an accurate estimation of what the real robot would do?
- If yes, shall I assume that Isaac Sim is the problem and that the real robot would correctly execute the route as planned by moveit with the right time?

I ask this because I need to pick items in motion.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* birkett! This is an excellent first question, thank you for providing clear, concise background information and for clearly stating your questions. I haven't personally done anything with trajectories, but I hope to soon so I look forward to seeing what answers you get to this question!